# Woocommerce checkout not loading properly in custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am developing a WordPress plugin that has a page where users can select and purchase products on the same page. This page consists of product selection, a cart template, and a checkout template. Everything seems to be working fine except for a part of the checkout.

This is the checkout of my plugin when I select Paypal:

[image]

An this is the real /checkout/ page:

[image]

You can observe it is not the same.

On the `/checkout/` page of the website, the Paypal buttons load through ajax. In my plugin, the button is static and when clicked, it gives an error on the order **only in Paypal** method. I think because the button is not the native of Paypal.

When you change countries, the new calculation of prices is made, so I think the Woocommerce scripts are loading. In terms of code, I have this:

```
define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_checkout', '__return_true');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');
```

Everything works fine except for the final checkout button. The Paypal buttons do not work. I have tried using the checkout template and the cart template on this way: `wc_get_template( 'checkout/form-checkout.php' );` , but the page breaks.

It seems it is not loading some scripts for the payment methods. Is there any `wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-checkout' );` but with payment methods?

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the payment gateway methods scripts must be enqueued in the following way:

```
wp_enqueue_scripts( 'wc-payment-gateway' );
```

It is important to note that it is `wp_enqueue_scripts` and not `wp_enqueue_script`

Additionally, it should go in the `wp_footer` like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_payment_gateway_scripts' );

function enqueue_payment_gateway_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-checkout' );
   wp_enqueue_scripts( 'wc-payment-gateway' );
}
```